# How to play youtube Videos continuously like a playlist?

Tags: ios, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller, playlist, avqueueplayer

We are able to play youtube videos by fetching the data using `Youtube API` for iOS Application. We would like to play a set of videos continuously like a playlist. Can someone guide us through this issue. we tried using different players but none of them are working for youtube links. we have used `MPMoviePlayerViewController` but it doesn't play videos continuously, and `AVQueuePlayer` we were able to play MP4 videos stored in the app but unable to play youtube links.

It would be a great help if someone can help us
Thanks in advance.